# ASP.NET Core 3.0 HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

Im migration a classic `C# MVC` project to `.NET Core` and I have a Utility Project where I need to get access of `App_Data` folder.

I already create in this new project my `App_Data` folder outside `wwwroot` but I need to get reference to it from this Utility Project.

[image]

This is my old code:

```
 public static class Common
    {
      private static void DeleteTestFiles()
            {
                var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Files");
                .....
    }
}
```

I was reading that in 3.0 there is a way to do this, here the example:

```
 private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            string contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;

            return Content(webRootPath + "\n" + contentRootPath);
        }
```

But above code is for a Controller that lives in the web project. My Utility Projects common class is not a Controller and is a static class so I cannot have constructor in order to have `IWebHostEnvironment` to be injected automaticly.

> Any clue how can I do get the path or maybe I need to manually inject IWebHostEnvironment but don't have a clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**.Net 6 (.NetCore 3 and above)**
For example I want to locate ~/wwwroot/CSS

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

    public YourController (IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
        _webHostEnvironment= webHostEnvironment;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        string webRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        string contentRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath;

        string path ="";
        path = Path.Combine(webRootPath , "CSS");
        //or path = Path.Combine(contentRootPath , "wwwroot" ,"CSS" );
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Don't use a static class. You can keep something similar to your class, and register it as a singleton.

```
public class Common
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

    public Common(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    private void DeleteTestFiles()
    {
            var path = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "App_Data/Files");
            .....
    }
}
```

Then, in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSingleton<Common>();
```

Finally, inject `Common` where you need it, instead of just statically referencing the class. This is how things work in DI, statics are a no-go.

**UPDATE:**

In order this to work, because the Utility project is referencing `Microsoft.NETCore.App` and not `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` framework then you have to use `IHostEnvironment` instead of `IWebHostEnvironment`.

`IWebHostEnvironment` actually implements `IHostEnvironment` interface.

Did the test and all working good! I could get the `ContentRootPath`.

```
public class Common
    {
        private readonly IHostEnvironment _env;

        public Common(IHostEnvironment env)
        {
            _env = env;
        }

        private void DeleteTestFiles()
        {
                var path = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "App_Data/Files");
                .....
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but In case I want to get the IWebHostEnvironment  instantiated in my static class is there a way? Like IWebHostEnvironment  env = new something() ? Appreciate it

Comment: @VAAA what if you did HostingEnvironment env = new HostingEnvironment() ? both this class and IWebHostEnvironment implement IHostEnvironment

Comment: No. It's not possible. That's why I suggested this approach. Statics are not going to work here, so you're just going to have to get over it.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thanks a lot, do you know what nuget package do I have to reference to my Utility project in order to get IWebHostEnvironment  ?

Comment: I already tried to install different nuget packages and no one resolves the IWebHostEnvironment. And when right click "Quick actions and refactoring" it doesnt give me any install recomendation or something :(

Comment: Off the top of my head, no. However, it might require a framework reference. .NET Core 3.0 moved to using a framework reference, rather than package references for most components. If that is the case, you'll have to target .NET Core 3.1. That should not be an issue as any code that interacts with ASP.NET Core components will only be applicable to .NET Core targets, anyways, now.

Comment: Yeah, its already targeted to 3.1 but the framework is Microsoft.NetCore.App, I think i have to add Microsoft.AspNetCore.App framework in order to get the assembly. I will try to find out how to add a new framework

Comment: I already tried everything and cant get IWebHostEnvironment  resolved in this project, and is targeted 3.1 :(  I really appreciate any help I might be doing something horrible wrong.

Comment: Ok found the way, actually if the project is a class library and not the asp.net app, you cant uset IWebHostEnvironment, you have to use IHostEnvironment, because IWebHostEnvironment implements IHostEnvironment. I just ran the test and all amazing good.